# Finding a specific set in DB

Tags: java, sql, oracle

So my table is as below

```
cgid cid vid
--------------------
CG1   C1  V1
CG1   C2  V1
CG2   C1  V1
CG2   C2  V2
CG3   C1  V1
CG4   C2  V1
```

and so on

I will be having some thing like this in my java code

`[{cid=C1,vid=V1},{cid=C2,vid=V1}]`

and I need to find out specific CGID which represent this set in java.

Right now what I can do is get all CGIDs and compare one by one with all data, but as table size is growing it is becoming a problem. is there any other(easy) way to do it.

Any recommended query to fetch the cgid in a single query passing all input from java code.

Comment: Questions: (1) are all three columns constrained to `not null`? If not, how should `null` be handled? (2) Define "represent" a set. Does that mean that the set of pairs for a CGID must match a given set exactly? Does it mean that one set must be contained in the other (without necessarily being equal)? Are duplicates allowed in either set, and how is that handled? Perhaps "must have same multiplicity in both sets", or "disregard duplicates", or what else?

Comment: Consider all three as non null. Regarding set consider the there are four rows in frontbof one cgid then for two cgids it may be possible that 3 rlws are same and only 1 row is diff. also it can be possible that cg1 has 3 rows and cg2 has 4 rows three rows same as cg1 and one new. in that case I want to identify cg1 amd 2 separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a hack for your problem.

I included test data in the `with` clause. In real life you will have an actual table, and some way to provide the input. Here I provide the "table" as a view in the `with` clause, and the "target set" to which you must compare as another view, consisting of a string in the exact format you showed.

The first step is to break up the input string, so that the "target set" can be presented in the same format as the input table. That's done in the `norm_target` (normalized target) view calculation. If your target set is given in some different format, you will need to somehow be able to arrange it in the same way as the output of `norm_target`.

Then, for every set - including the target - I create a single string encoding all the elements - each token terminated by `#` (assuming this character does not appear anywhere in your `cid` and `vid` values; for a more robust solution, you can replace that with some control character, for example the "record separator" or the "system bell" from the ASCII character set). The single string encoding, in each case, is ordered by `cid, vid`.

Two sets have the same single-string encoding if and only if the sets have the same pairs. Either value (or both) in a pair can be `null` - concatenating `#` to everything results in `null` being treated as a proper empty string, not the generic `null` of Oracle tradition. Also, if there are duplicates, then the number of duplicates of each distinct pair in the two sets must match exactly.

Compared to the "correct" solutions, which would require collections of some sort, or direct comparison of JSON strings (in more recent versions of Oracle), etc., this will probably be faster. It is a hack: a solution that should be 100% correct, just not the standard way one would or should solve the problem; but which provides some benefit that the "standard way" doesn't.

```
with
  my_table (cgid, cid, vid) as (
    select 'CG1', 'C1', 'V1' from dual union all
    select 'CG1', 'C2', 'V1' from dual union all
    select 'CG2', 'C1', 'V1' from dual union all
    select 'CG2', 'C2', 'V2' from dual union all
    select 'CG3', 'C1', 'V1' from dual union all
    select 'CG4', 'C2', 'V1' from dual
  )
, target (i_set) as (
    select '[{cid=C1,vid=V1},{cid=C2,vid=V1}]'
    from   dual
  )
, norm_target (cid, vid) as (
    select  regexp_substr(i_set, '\{cid=([^,]*)', 1, level, null, 1) as cid,
            regexp_substr(i_set, ',vid=([^}]*)' , 1, level, null, 1) as vid
    from    target
    connect by level <= regexp_count(i_set, '\{')
  )
select cgid
from   my_table
group  by cgid
having listagg(cid || '#' || vid || '#') within group (order by cid, vid) =
       (
         select listagg(cid || '#' || vid || '#') 
                  within group (order by cid, vid)
         from   norm_target
       )
;

CGID
--------
CG1
```